# How can I start a new android activity using a string? intent android activity

Tags: android, string, android-intent, android-activity

I need start a new android activity using a string,

The main src name is: AlphabetListDemo.java

The activit name class that i want to run is: videoviewted.java

This is the src from AlphabetListDemo.java:

http://pastebin.com/3hrz8Yms

I've tried with this but it gives me error:

http://pastebin.com/pBxZFUTV

Thanks by the help.

Comment: What error message/logcat output do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the string you need in the Intent

```
intent.putExtra("myString",<some string>);
startActivity(intent);
```

And you can retreive it like this

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String myString = getIntent().getStringExtra("myString");
    ...
}
```

Comment: I try with   Intent i = new Intent(this, videoviewted.class );
             String prod_arr[] = {"A"};
             prod_arr = new String[0];
             startActivity(i);

Comment: you must call intent.putExtra(prod_arr) before calling startActivity